# Using Promise.all when needing to conditionally set field in an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, expo

Thanks in advance for your help. I am building a React Native Expo App.

I have a function that makes an API call that returns an array of objects with various fields. Importantly, each object has 2-4 assets that need to be downloaded and stored locally.

Currently, I am iterating through the response, checking which fields each object has, then calling a store() function that stores it, and returns the new local uri, which I replace the orignal URL with.

```
await axios
            .get(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_URL)
            .then(async (res) => {
                for (obj of res.data.entries()) {
                    if (obj.image) {
                        obj.image = await saveImage(obj.image, obj.name, "image")
                    }
                    if (obj.secondaryImage) {
                        obj.secondaryImage = await saveImage(obj.secondaryImage, obj.name, "secondaryImage")
                    }
                    if (obj.logo) {
                        obj.logo = await saveImage(obj.logo, obj.name, "logo")
                    }
                    if (obj.datasheet) {
                        obj.datasheet = await saveImage(obj.datasheet, obj.name, "datasheet")
                    }
                }
                await AsyncStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

I know I should use Promise.all() to make performance better, but I still need to conditionally set each field that exists to that returned value.

Any ideas on how I can do that or just make this code more efficiant at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any value as an element of the array to `Promise.all`, not just promises. They just get coerced to an immediately-fulfilled promise using `Promise.resolve()`, which won't need to be waited for. Thus you can pass `undefined` (or `null`, or any default value) that you want to assign to the property:

```
const res = await axios.get(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_URL)
for (obj of res.data.entries()) {
    [obj.image, obj.secondaryImage, obj.logo, obj.datasheet] = await Promise.all([
        obj.image && saveImage(obj.image, obj.name, "image"),
        obj.secondaryImage && saveImage(obj.secondaryImage, obj.name, "secondaryImage"),
        obj.logo && saveImage(obj.logo, obj.name, "logo"),
        obj.datasheet && saveImage(obj.datasheet, obj.name, "datasheet"),
    ]);
}
await AsyncStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

Alternatively, use a helper function:

```
function saveImageProperty(obj, propertyName) {
    if (obj[propertyName]) {
        obj[propertyName] = await saveImage(obj[propertyName], obj.name, propertyName);
    }
}
const res = await axios.get(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_URL)
for (obj of res.data.entries()) {
    await Promise.all([
        saveImageProperty(obj, "image"),
        saveImageProperty(obj, "secondaryImage"),
        saveImageProperty(obj, "logo"),
        saveImageProperty(obj, "datasheet"),
    ]);
}
await AsyncStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

You could further speed this up by running all iterations of the loop concurrently, but depending on the size of the `res.data` array, that might overwhelm the `saveImage` throughput.